# function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement

Tags: sql, greenplum

I get the error "function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement"

when I try to execute the following function. The function uses the value from generate_series and just returns 'yes' or 'no'

```
SELECT generate_series, vin_temp_test(generate_series) FROM options_t
```

options_t has the following data

[image]

Comment: What is the argument to `vin_temp_test()`?  Where is `options_test` being used?

Comment: Where is the definition of vin_temp_test().

Comment: Greenplum is not PostgreSQL 8.4, please stop using that tag. This looks like a totally Greenplum-specific problem, actually, as it'd be perfectly valid on PostgreSQL.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? Im' having the same issue